# How to modify QuickSort such that pivot is at its correct position

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Consider an array as below,

```
int[] a = {100, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
```

Consider the middle element is always taken as the pivot.

```
pivot = 10
```

The standard quick sort algorithm looks as follows

```
public void quickSort(int[] a, int low, int high) {
        if (a == null || a.length == 0)
                return;

        if (low >= high)
                return;

        int pivotIndex = partition( a, low, high );
        quickSort(a, low, pivotIndex-1);
        quickSort(a, pivotIndex, high);
    }

    public int partition ( int[] a, int low, int high )
    {
        // pick the pivot
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        int pivot = a[middle];

        while (low <= high) {
            while (a[low] < pivot) {
                    low++;
            }

            while (a[high] > pivot) {
                    high--;
            }

            if (low <= high) {
                    swap( a, low, high );
                    low++;
                    high--;
            }
        }

        return low;
    }
```

Upon completing one iteration of the while loop, (pivoting around 10), the array looks as follows

```
 high          low 
  10 1 2 3 4 5 100 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

As you can see, the pivot element is at index 0, which is not the correct position of 10.

My question is, **how can I modify the above algorithm such that at the end of every iteration, the pivot element is at the correct position, and we proceed to recurse on the left and right halves without considering the pivot**

Comment: Looks suspiciously like a homework question. The answer is pretty obvious too. Perhaps you should let us know what, according to you, is the right way to go about it. We can take it up from there.

Comment: The question asks about one iteration of the while loop. The pivot isn't supposed to end up in it's correct position until the while loop completes all iterations (when low > high in the example code). The partition code may need a small fix. The example code is similar to [Hoare partition scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme), in which case the pivot will end up in the left or right partition. Code could be added to exclude the pivot and adjacent elements equal to the pivot value.

Comment: Looks working correctly when I copied the copy and tested in my environment.

Comment: @rcgldr, but why isn't pivot supposed to end up in it's correct position until the while loop completes all iterations. The algorithm would make so much more sense, if it could be done that way. Are you sure it cannot be done?

Comment: @Quirk, definitely not homework. I have my ideas, but didn't put it here, since I didn't want to influence the answer. But here it goes, the reason, what I am asking for is not happening, is because, we blindly do low++ and high-- after swapping. This should be avoided, since it's possible that low or high, is the correct position of pivot, but by doing low++ or high--, we're letting go of that. Let me know how you would do it.

Comment: @additionster It is working correctly. My question is, how can I modify the above algorithm such that at the end of every iteration, the pivot element is at the correct position, and we proceed to recurse on the left and right halves without considering the pivot

Comment: @PepperBoy you *can't.* Because you don't know the correct position of the pivot after just one iteration.

Comment: @rcgldr hmm, I didn't quite get you there. Say, the while loop was (low < high), not (low <= high), what changes would I have to make to ensure that by the end of this iteration, pivot is at the correct position?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to get the pivot value(s) in its(their) correct position at the start, the code could do a single scan of the array, checking for values less than, equal to, or greater than pivot, for example generating three counts: ltpivot = # elements < pivot value, eqpivot = # elements == pivot, gtpivot = # elements > pivot value. (Only two counts would be need to be generated by scanning, the third count would be (high + 1 - low - (2 of the counts)). Then all the pivot values should be moved to index locations low + ltpivot to low + ltpivot + eqpivot - 1. This could be done with yet another pass to swap the pivot values into place. Then a third pass could be done to swap elements less than or greater than pivot to the left or right of the pivot(s).

The issue is that this method would be slower than standard quicksort, requiring 3 scans of the array versus what is effectively a single scan with standard quicksort. Standard quicksort will only correctly place one pivot element, leaving any other elements == pivot scattered, but in typical cases, this is not an issue. (One of the worst cases for standard quick sort is all values the same).

Comment: "Standard quicksort will only correctly place one pivot element". Please see my example above, I don't see even one element being placed in the correct position. 10 which is the pivot in the first iteration, is not placed in the correct position.

Comment: can you please point me to what you refer to as the "standard quicksort" implementation. My reference to "standard quicksort" is the one implemented above, and as I stated, 10, is not in it's correct position, at the end of the iteration. It should be index 5, whereas, this algorithm places it at index 0.

Comment: if you could kindly point me to one web link to this implementation you are talking about, it would be awesome, and I could debug and see how it works. Almost everything that I can google comes with a while (low <= high) implementation, where they do a low++;high--; after swap, and this does not help pivot be at it's correct position.

Comment: @PepperBoy - I deleted my prior comments. With the post decrement and post increment partition function in the example code, the while (low <= high) is ok. With quicksort, the pivot element (or an element equal to pivot element) will not end up in the correct position until the while loop exits. The wiki example for [Hoare partition scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) use pre-increment and pre-decrement . The pivot value doesn't have to be A[lo], it can be any value in the array like the middle A[(lo + hi)/2].